# Can I develop to the Delivery Plans for Team Foundation Server 2018?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to change the UI of Delivery Plans for TFS2018, is there a way to do that? maybe a designer? Let's say I want to sum the story points of each column and add it to the UI somewhere.. or maybe set each feature colour by its project (instead of the default colour per work item type)?

Can I do those stuff and how?

Answer (score 1):

There is no place where you can configure/design the delivery plans feature, but like everything in the Web UI of Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server is extensible using extensions.

This comes with a giant caveat, I don't think that Delivery Plans is supported for extensibility, meaning it may break when Microsoft releases a newer version of it. Technically there won't be anything blocking you though (apart from the lack of documentation).

You can find more information on the Extensibility SDK right here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/overview?view=vsts